# Getting a value from gridview with checkbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview

[image]

i have this gridview and im trying to print out the MMBR_PROM_ID of whichever column is checked by the user.

(Default.apsx)

```
Welcome to ASP.NET!

    </h2>

            <div style="width: 700px; height: 370px; overflow: auto; float: left;">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerValue" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Generate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="grdViewCheck" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Generate" />

</asp:Content>
```

(Default.aspx.cs)

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FrontOffEntities tmpdb = new FrontOffEntities();

            List<MMBR_PROM> newListMMBR_Prom = tmpdb.MMBR_PROM.ToList();


            GridView1.DataSource = newListMMBR_Prom;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

so my goal is when i press generate i want to be able to print out as string all the MMBR_PROM_ID which is checked by the user. im kinda new to aspnet so im having a hard time coping up with the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your mentioned requirements you can try the below given code to get the values of the **MMBR_PROM_ID** from **Gridview1** on Generate Button Click.

```
     //For every row in the grid
     foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Find the checkbox in the current row being pointed named as grdViewCheck
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)r.FindControl("grdViewCheck");

            //Print the value in the reponse for the cells[1] which is MMBR_PROM_ID
            if (chk!=null && chk.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write(r.Cells[1].Text);
            }
        }
```

Here, cells[1] refers to the Cell Index of the Specific row, in your case it is **MMBR_PROM_ID**, which you want to print. Hope this helps!

If you are looking for a comma seperated value of **MMBR_PROM_ID**, the below mentioned code will work for you.

```
     //Declaration of string variable 
     string str="";

     //For every row in the grid
     foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Find the checkbox in the current row being pointed named as grdViewCheck
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)r.FindControl("grdViewCheck");

            //Print the value in the reponse for the cells[1] which is MMBR_PROM_ID
            if (chk!=null && chk.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write(r.Cells[1].Text);
                //appending the text in the string variable with a comma
                str = str + r.Cells[1].Text + ", ";
            }
        }
      //Printing the comma seperated value for cells[1] which is MMBR_PROM_ID
      Response.Write(str);
```

Comment: thanks it worked. how could i seperate it with comma? and put it under the generate button?

Comment: Are you looking to see all the checked rows MMBR_PROM_ID in a comma seperated string? If yes, then you need to declare a string variable above foreach, and use stringVar += r.cells[1].Text + "," inside the if condition

Comment: how to declare the string variable?

Comment: I have posted another code, which I think will fulfill your requirements.